# Origin of the Socle of a module

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, ho.history-overview

Where does the notation $\mbox{Soc}(M)$ (the sum of all simple submodules of a module $M$) first appear?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/082184900X) by J. Lambek says on page 168 that the notion of socle (for modules) is due to Dieudonne. In [this paper](https://eudml.org/doc/86762), the word "socle" is used by Dieudonne, and he explains that he follows M.R. Remak, who first introduced the notion of socle for finite groups, as a subgroup generated by all minimal normal subgroups. However, I cannot find yet where the notation "Soc" appears first (in the context of modules).

Hope this bit of information helps. Cheers!

Comment: According to Richard Brauer http://www.jstor.org/stable/1989943 the notion of socle (sockel) at least for groups goes back to G. Frobenius, Theorie der hyperkomplexen Grossen, Sitzungsberichte der Preussischen
Akademie der Wissenschaften, 1903, pp. 504-537.

Answer (score 3):

Just to establish some more reference points:

In the book
`[Curtis, Charles W.; Reiner, Irving. Representation theory of finite groups and associative algebras. Pure and Applied Mathematics, Vol. XI Interscience Publishers, a division of John Wiley & Sons, New York-London 1962`],
the socle of a module is defined, but no special notation is used.

In the paper
`[Curtis, C. W.; Jans, J. P. On algebras with a finite number of indecomposable modules. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 114 1965 122--132.]`,
the notation $S(M)$ is used.

In the book
`[Anderson, Frank W.; Fuller, Kent R. Rings and categories of modules. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Vol. 13. Springer-Verlag, New York-Heidelberg, 1974]`,
the notation ${Soc} \; M$ is used.